# MouseOut event fires on dijit.form.Select when going to item list

Tags: events, dojo

I decided to take the advice of the below and rework my question to be simpler.

The issue I am having is that I have a `dijit.form.Select` dijit in a custom dijit that is display onMouseOver and hidden onMouseOut. This is caused due to the onMouseOut event being fired when opening the Select and going to the list of items. This causes the onMouseOut event to fire and close my custom dijit.

Best I can figure is because Select inherits from `dijit._HasDropDown` and the drop down piece is actually created directly under the body node instead of within the dijit, thus it believes that when mousing over that part it has left and fires the onMouseOut.

Is this really the way that should work and I'm just doing it wrong? I'm really at a loss as to how to get this to work, hopefully this is better and will attract a few more views.

Comment: I think you should refine your investigation on what your problem really is rather than pasting the full code of your widget, then post only the interesting part. We don't even know how you use that widget on your page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, the onMouseOut event occurs on your custom widget because the Select's drop down, like all drop downs in dijit, is attached directly to .

One approach: the focus manager will set this.focused your widget when the widget *and it's descendants*, as a unit, gain/lose focus.   So you could ignore the blur even on your widget when this.focused==true.

One complication though is what to do when the drop down extends past the bottom of your custom widget.   In that case clicking the drop down will close the drop down, thus putting the cursor outside of your custom widget, but there will be no onmouseout event since the cursor didn't cross the border of your widget.   Maybe that's what you want anyway.